# ASP.NET MVC 4 jQuery ajax request returning my custom 404 html as a 200 response when URI not found

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax call on a button press. If I have `customErrors mode="On"` and my ajax request URI is not found, the `404` html is being returned to the request as a `200` status.

`web.config`

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Errors">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/Error404" />
</customErrors>
```

JS run on button click.

```
$.get(api_uri, function (json) {
    console.log(json);
    options.element_to_inject.html(compiled_template(json));
    options.status_container.hide();
}).fail(function () {
    options.status_container.hide();
    options.element_to_inject.html("Error").show();
});
```

My controller method being called by my AJAX request.

```
public JsonResult Get(int? id)
{
    // Do work
}
```

`console.log(json)` as shown above is outputting my `404` html. If I turn `customErrors mode="Off"` then I get back an actual `404` response code as needed.

Thought: It's almost as if I need ajax requests to ignore the custom `404`.

How with `customErrors mode="On"` can I get my request to not return the `404` html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the error url a controller/action?  If so, use

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
     Response.StatusCode = 404;
     Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
}
```

**Update**

The problem with 404 is that it is often generated by the framework before it gets to your code.  You can not handle it with a `customError` tag but that will apply regardless of whether the request is an AJAX request or not.  If you want to handle it with a custom error page but want to retain the error code, redirect to a controller/action to generate the custom error page and, as part of the action, set the response code and turn off IIS handling of the custom error.  Note: you can do this only for AJAX requests by checking
to see if it is an AJAX request and only setting the response code if it is.

Comment: I added more detail to the question.